# List view css question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, css

I have web part section where I have following code:

```
<style type="text/css">

/* List View Header */
.ms-listviewtable > thead > tr > th {
 background-color: #5B9BD5;
}

/* List view Header Text color*/
.ms-vh-div,  .ms-headerSortTitleLink {
color:white!important; font-weight: bold;
} 

/* background color for alternate rows */
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr.ms-alternating {
background: #DDEBF7;
}

.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr td{
border-bottom: 1px dotted black !important;
}
</style>
```

Problem that I have some issue with border bottom after each column:
[image]
How to make it accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code.

```
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr td{
border-bottom: 1px dotted black !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to remove dotted line. I just want to make it accurate near borders.

Comment: Image is too bad to see the border. What do you mean with issue? Double dots at where columns begin and end?

Comment: Newbie, more detailed screen - http://imgur.com/a/3sqYI

Comment: IE - http://imgur.com/a/4wzmh